# Climbing Stairs Problem What about the last step you must take

Tags: dynamic-programming

Need help understanding the last bit of this solution. Turns out this is a problem many people are familiar with. In which have to find the number of distinct ways you can climb N stairs while only being able to climb either 1 or 2 steps.

```
class climbStairs {
    
    public static int climbStairs(int n) {
        

        int[] ways = new int[n];
        ways[0] = 1;
        ways[1] = 2;

        for (int i=2; i < n; n++)
            ways[i] = ways[i-1]+ways[i-2];

        return ways[n-1];

    }
}
```

This code correctly calculates the number. however I am stuck understanding a crucial part of this.

I understand that only way to get to Nth step you had to be on N-1 or N-2 step therefor you have to add together the numbers of ways to get to N-1 and N-2.

What I don't quite understand completely is. What about the last step when you standing at at N-2 or N-1 steps.... Isn't there one last step you must make to reach Nth step...

I keeps searching for an explanation to this but i can't find it anywhere. Could someone that understands it try to explain it to me please?

Comment: Yes, when you are on the step `N-2` or `N-1` you need to do one "move" to get to the step `N`. What exactly is the problem you have?

Comment: You're counting the starting position ways[0] as 1, which makes up for the last step. btw, in your code `n++` should be `i++`

Answer (score 0):

Exactly. To reach the nth step, we add all the ways to reach the (n-1)th step and all the ways to reach the (n-2)th step. We could have taken our "last step" from either of these.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.HashMap;

/***
 * This class finds the numbers of ways in which someone can climb
 * stairs given their are only two possibilities either take 1 step
 * or 2 step at a time. This solution uses the approach of Dynamic
 * programming. Base cases are n=0 or n=1 the number ways will be 1.
 * Uses a hashmap for memoization.
 *
 */
public class ClimbStairs {
    public static int climbStairs(int n) {

        HashMap<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();
        int ways = 0;

        if (n <= 1) {

            ways = 1;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            if (i <= 1) {
                hm.put(i, 1);

            } else {
                System.out.println("inside here");
                ways = hm.get(i - 1).intValue() + hm.get(i - 2).intValue();
                hm.put(i, ways);
            }

        }
        return ways;

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n = climbStairs(2);
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).